# Angular JS grouping objects

Tags: angularjs, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
$scope.monthTasks = [object,object,...,object];
```

Each object is as follows:

```
Object={
"emp_id": 1,
"task_id":212,
"project_id":2,
"task_name":"Updating UI",
"tasks": [
            {
             "task_date": "2016-9-14",
             "hours": 2,
             "minutes": 15
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

I have multiple such objects with the with different `task_date`. I want to group these objects by date as several tasks can have same the date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to show them together in the HTMLß

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not such an easy way, but I would create dictionary whose key is `task_date`.
I assume that each object could have multiple tasks, which makes the problem more complex.
So my solution would be as follows:

http://codepen.io/kei-sato/pen/qaLRLZ

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  var monthTasks = [
    { id: 1, tasks: [{ task_date: '2016-9-13' }, { task_date: '2016-9-14' }] },
    { id: 2, tasks: [{ task_date: '2016-9-12' }] },
    { id: 3, tasks: [{ task_date: '2016-9-11' }, { task_date: '2016-9-14' }] },
    { id: 4, tasks: [{ task_date: '2016-9-10' }] },
  ];

  var monthTasksDict = monthTasks.reduce((dict, monthTask) => {
    monthTask.tasks.forEach(task => {
      var taskDate = task.task_date;
      dict[taskDate] = dict[taskDate] || [];
      dict[taskDate].push(monthTask);
    });
    return dict;
  }, {});

  var monthTasksWithTaskDate = Object.keys(monthTasksDict).map(taskDate => ({ task_date: taskDate, monthTasks: monthTasksDict[taskDate] }));
  $scope.monthTasksWithTaskDate = monthTasksWithTaskDate;

}]);
```

html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="monthTasks in monthTasksWithTaskDate | orderBy: 'task_date'">
      task_date: {{ task_date }}
      <li ng-repeat="monthTask in monthTasks">
        id: {{ monthTask.id }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- External Libraries -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use filter a for it. The orderBy filter is available for it.
You can use it like this orderBy : task_date.
Like here:

```
 {{ [{
    'name': 'Ari',
    'status': 'awake'
    }, {
    'name': 'Q',
    'status': 'sleeping'
    }, {
    'name': 'Nate',
    'status': 'awake'
 }] | orderBy: 'name' }}

<!--
    [
    {"name":"Ari","status":"awake"},
    {"name":"Nate","status":"awake"},
    {"name":"Q","status":"sleeping"}
    ]
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions to filter your results

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasksToFilter() | filter:filterTask">
        <b>{{task['tasks'][0]['task_date']}}</b>
        <li ng-repeat="mytask in result(task)">{{mytask.task_name}}</li>        
  </div>
```

Functions

```
$scope.tasksToFilter = function() {
        CachedTasks = [];
        return $scope.json;
    }

    $scope.filterTask = function(task) {

        var newTask = CachedTasks.indexOf(task["tasks"][0]["task_date"]) == -1;
        if (newTask) {
            CachedTasks.push(task["tasks"][0]["task_date"]);
            console.log(CachedTasks);
        }
        return newTask;
    }

    $scope.result = function(currenttask)
    {
        var groupvalues = [];
      for(var i=0;i<$scope.json.length;i++)
      {
        if($scope.json[i]['tasks'][0]['task_date'] == currenttask['tasks'][0]['task_date'])
        {
            groupvalues.push($scope.json[i]);
        }
      }
      return groupvalues;
    }
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/6t3b9mzy/13/)**